# What means class name starting with = symbol in sass?

Tags: sass

I found in bulma css source class starting with =

```
=button-small
  border-radius: $radius-small
  font-size: 11px
  height: 24px
  line-height: 16px
  padding-left: 6px
  padding-right: 6px
```

[src](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/sass/elements/button.sass)

What does it mean? I couldn't find it in google...

Comment: See: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixin-content

Comment: AFAIK this is called sass shorthand syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [**SASS**](http://sass-lang.com/guide) syntax for mixins.

[image]